# How would one create a guild and then give myself an invite link

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so I am currently in the process of trying to have a bot create a new guild/discord server and then console.log() an invite link for that so that I can join the guild and set it up to then invite friends. However, I am running into some slight problems as I am unsure as to how to go about this. My thought process is the following:

```
run : function(msg, client, cmds, disc, args){
    const guild = client.guild.create("New Guild");
    let invite //(and here get a new guild invite code )
    console.log(invite);
}
```

My first problem is that I am not even sure if the guild creation is valid and how to get a guild invite from a guild object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed it was that previously the object that it fetched was a category channel object meanwhile I needed a text channel/voice channel to create an invite. The solution I used was the following:

```
run : function(msg, client, cmds, disc, args){
        client.guilds.create("New Guild")
            .then(value => {
                value.channels.create('new-general', { reason: 'Needed a cool new channel' })
                .then(channel => {
                    let invite = channel.createInvite()
                        .then(invite => console.log(invite))
                        .catch(console.error);
                    console.log(invite.url);
                })
                .catch(console.error);
            })
            .catch(console.error);

    }
```

To explain the fix, I had to create a channel in the server to invite someone so before I created an invite I created a new channel and used the newly created channel as the channel for the invite.

Answer (score 0):

I have semi-completed what I wished to do. However, this is not the final thing because there is an error messaged:

```
    DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\jonas\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\jonas\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/801898492082782310/invites',
  code: 10003,
  httpStatus: 404
```

I am unsure what the reason for the error in getting the correct channel but I'll reply to this with the full code when I have solved the problem.

```
run : function(msg, client, cmds, disc, args){
        //console.log("1");
        client.guilds.create("New Guild")
            .then(value => {
                let channel = value.channels.cache.first();
                let invite = channel.createInvite({
                  maxAge: 0, // 0 = infinite expiration
                  maxUses: 0 // 0 = infinite uses
                })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .catch(console.error);
                console.log(invite.url);
            })
            .catch(console.error);

}
```